# Xdebug doesn't stop on breakpoints even when it logs a break, but says it is connected to client

Tags: debugging, phpstorm, breakpoints, xdebug, remote-debugging

I've been trying for a couple weeks to get my PHPStorm to connect to a remote host via Xdebug.  Most recently I discovered that the client's host blocked port 9000.  I finally have that fixed and now the xdebug log shows that it's connecting to the client (me, of course).

However, it doesn't stop on any breakpoints.  Breakpoints set in PHPStorm don't even show up in the log.  calling `xdebug_break();` at least gets logged as a break, but it still doesn't stop.

based on other questions here I've confirmed that xdebug is loaded with `zend_extention=/full/path/xdebug.so` and not with `extension=xdebug.so`

I've also tried switching from port 9000 to port 9001, with no change in the results.

The log entry is:

```
Log opened at 2015-06-09 14:41:10  //and many other dates and times
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Remote address found, connecting to MY.IP.HE.RE:9000.  //similar message on port 9001 after trying that
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///chroot/home/company/remotehost.com/html/index.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="2294" idekey="PHPSTORM"><engine version="2.2.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2013 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///chroot/home/company/remotehost.com/html/app/code/community/Zzyzzx/Stores/controllers/TestController.php" lineno="11"></xdebug:message></response>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2015-06-09 14:41:13
```

The file it's getting that from has 3 breakpoints set in the IDE and one coded in on line 11.

**What might be causing it to fail to follow breakpoints and let me debug?**

The path that I used in the server settings was `/home/company/remotehost.com/html` mapped to my project root, which contains the same files.  I understand this to be the absolute path from root, and if i understand it's confirmed by the log showing a break from the code.  It is the only file with a path set.  Do I need to set the path for EVERY file?

I also tried deleting the server in hopes of triggering the dialog, but it wasn't triggered, I just get exactly the same log entry with the new time/date/IP.

I just discovered that whenever I attempted to reload the page i'm debugging, in my "run" menu there is an option to "resume program" which brings up a list with the file i'm trying to debug.  clicking on that opens the debug tool window where the message "waiting for connection from JetBrains IDE Support extension for Chrome..." is displayed.  Isn't this for debugging javascript?  Is it trying to debug my PHP as Javascript?

Also I tried using a couple of other xdebug clients with similar results.  it connects and then gives the same messages.  Makes me think it's not PHPStorm.

Everything I've tried was trying to debug the following code:

```
    class Zzyzzx_Stores_TestController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "in the controller 1 <br />";
        xdebug_break();
        echo "in the controller 2 ";
        //3 commented lines of unused code
        //
        //
        phpinfo();
        //2 commented lines of unused code
        //
    }
}
```

Breaks are set in the ide on each "echo", and of course you can see the coded break.

Debugging this locally worked fine.

Comment: Missing path mappings, most likely. 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/quickstart/debugger.html 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: So .. did you managed to solve it?

Comment: No, not yet.  It's on the back burner for a couple days because of the client.  Path mapping looks okay.  is there a way to remove all mapping and force it to do the wizard again?

Comment: also, @LazyOne can you confirm if the path map should be absolute from root, or relative to the project?

Comment: 1) Yes -- just delete that "Server" entry (or change host name there) -- if IDE does not see any entry with correct `hostname:port` pair it will trigger that little dialog/wizard again. 2) The remote path should be an **absolute** path from the root. Also make sure that it's final/resolved path (i.e. no symlinks in it) -- It's how xdebug works -- it resolves all symlinks and works with final path only.

Comment: @LazyOne I checked the path previously, and should have mentioned that in my question.  It may have been wrong though.  I'm adding details to the question about it.  Also, I deleted the server and it still didn't trigger the dialog.  It just gave exactly the same entry in the log.

Comment: *"Do I need to set the path for EVERY file?"* If no symbolic links .. then setting one path for the project root is enough (all subfolders will inherit the path)

Comment: *"The path that I used in the server settings was /home/company/remotehost.com/html"* The path from the log starts with `/chroot/` which differs to the one you have set.

Comment: Go trough all settings pages and look for any fields that have numbers (port number) and make sure that they do not have xdebug port there entered by mistake. That port (9000 by default) should be in one place only where it is clear that it is for xdebug. If not sure -- show screenshots.

Comment: Well ... that's possible that it's not PhpStorm who listens on xdebug port then. It could be different app .. or it could be PhpStorm but another service (I have seen that -- people changing numbers without reading the docs .. and this behaviour sounds **VERY** similar) .. hence incoming connection is not got served by the debugger.

Comment: Do you have php/xdebug installed locally? If so -- can you debug a simple local CLI script ("PHP Script" type of Run/Debug Configuration)

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne for sticking with me and helping so much.  I really appreciate it.  I've added another edit with some new details.  to answer your questions: with or without /chroot/ I get the same result. - no symlinks - no other 9000s - netstat gives the PID of PHPStorm as the listener - I'll try and run a simple debug and comment again.

Comment: *"... Isn't this for debugging javascript? Is it trying to debug my PHP as Javascript?"* Yes -- that's JS debugger. You must be using wrong Run/Debug Configuration entry.

Comment: @LazyOne I don't have any run/debug configurations setup, only the defaults.  How do I make it run it as PHP?  Also I tried it with a different client (XDC: XDebugClient from https://code.google.com/p/xdebugclient/ ) and got exactly the same result.  it sees the coded break but doesn't break.

Comment: Please see links in my very first comment for debugging manual. It has enough material to make debugging working (at very least most people finding it clear enough). As I have said: try local debugging of very basic script first. Then Try remote for the same simple script. And only then move to real code.

Answer (score 3):

One reason the breakpoints won't work is due to the odd case-sensitivity of Mac OSX.

I've found that if a filename doesn't match the case of the class the breakpoints for just that one file won't work, even though the rest of the application debugs fine, and "break at first line" shows the debugger is generally working.

The filesystem on OSX is essentially case insensitive, but strangely the command-line is case-sensitive which can fool you into thinking it's more like other case-sensitive Unixes. This then lulls you into believing there cannot ever be a case-mismatch because it would be totally broken and you'd notice!

However I feel OSX really operates more like Windows - very forgiving in this respect, until you upload your files to Linux server...

I had a class called `LegacyJsonMetadataMapper`  in `LegacyJSONMetadataMapper.php`. The autoloader works fine, the app works fine, PHPStorm doesn't mention the difference in case - I didn't notice it. But it simply would not fire any breakpoints. An hour of fiddling with mappings and server configs later (which have been working for years!), then I read [a PHPStorm bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18579) which mentioned this aspect on the side. I changed the case, and the breakpoints now work.

Note, this also happens if any folder in the namespace path doesn't match the case of the namespace "slugs" too. I just had this same problem (some breakbpoints working, some not).

Comment: I may have had this issue myself. I moved the docroot out of a folder with a capital letter, re-started PHPStorm and opened the project in the new folder, set the port to 9001 in xdebug and phpstorm and it finally worked. It could have been the restart of PHPStorm but I'd been trying port 9001 before. This is a potential +1 for case-sensitivity.